# Find the largest numer for array after operation

Tags: algorithm

Tom wants to find the maximum value after doubling each element in an array. He defines f(i) as: the maximum value of the array after doubling the i-th element. Tom expects to find the values of f(1) to f(n), where n is the length of this array. For example, if the array sequence is 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, then the output result would be: 5, 6, 5, 10, 8.

Comment: Why should any of us cheat you out of the benefit that you'd get from trying to solve this yourself first? Why should we cheat the site by directly answering such a low-quality homework-dump question?

Comment: Please read: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)